# Check if click trigger event is from button a or b

Tags: jquery, triggers

I have the following HTML situation, this is an example, the IDs and classes are different:

```
<div id="form-popup">
    <form id="a" class="hide"></form>
    <form id="b" class="hide"></form>
<div>

<button id="btn-a">Trigger Form A</button>
<button id="btn-b">Trigger Form B</button>
```

The above situation is that when button `#btn-a` is triggered the `#form-popup` will show up. This situation cannot be changed, and therefore (I think) I need to trigger `#btn-a` when `#btn-b` is clicked:

```
$('#btn-b').click(function(){
    $('#btn-a').trigger('click');
});
```

What I am trying to do is at the same time hiding the linked forms. So hiding form `#a` with `#btn-b` and form `#b` with `#btn-a`. I have tried some jQuery solutions, but I arrive in a loop, due to the fact that `#btn-a` has a double function; triggering the `#form-popup` and also hiding a certain form.

I was thinking of putting an if-statement to define where the click event comes from, but I'm not sure how? Or perhaps there is a better solution?

So the below situation causes the obvious loop:

```
$('#btn-a').click(function(){
    $('#a').removeClass('hide');
    $('#b).addClass('hide');
});
$('#btn-b').click(function(){
    $('#a').addClass('hide');
    $('#b').removeClass('hide');
    $('#a').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: Hello to anyone who is interested; solution is not found yet due to unresponsiveness from below replies. If you can help out, please!

Answer (score 0):

**IF YOU CANNOT EDIT THE BUTTONS** :

You can get the a or b from the id like so :

```
$('button').click(function(){
   var formId = ($(this).attr('id').split("-"))[1];

   $('form').hide();
   $('#'+formId).show();
});
```

See : [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wq9m0dx1/)

**However if you can edit the buttons :** :

What you could do is do a generic event on buttons or on a specified class such as form-button and then  get the **data-form-id** from the button which specify which form to show and then show it :

**HTML** :

```
<div id="form-popup">
    <form id="a" class="hide"><input type="text"></form>
    <form id="b" class="hide"><input type="text"></form>
<div>

<button class="form-button" data-form-id="a">Trigger Form A</button>
<button class="form-button" data-form-id="b">Trigger Form B</button>
```

**Javascript** :

```
$('.form-button').click(function(){
   var formId = $(this).data('form-id');

   $('form').hide();
   $('#'+formId).show();
});
```

See : [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vnohsma3/1/)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I cannot add a new attribute to the button (buttons are generated through php), only by adding another 2 JS events `.attr('data-form-id', 'a').` That's not ideal.

Comment: See my edit, made an answer without changing the button

Comment: Could you explain what refers to `.form-button`?

Comment: My bad I forgot to add the class to the button, but in your case if you can't modify your button attributes/class, juste use the first part of my answer, you could as well not use button but only select the button you want instead of EVERY button of the page

Comment: I understand what you have done with your solution, and it would work if this HTML is exactly like this, so you could split up with a and b. But this was just an HTML example; the real case scenario has different ID names and button classes, so I am not sure how to apply this. Is there no other way with an if-statement, to say if this button will be triggered than this, and else this will happen?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#btn-a, #btn-b").click(function(e){
if(e.currentTarget.id == 'btn-a')
{
    $("form#a").removeClass('hide');
    $("form#b").addClass('hide');

}
else
{
    $("form#b").removeClass('hide');
    $("form#a").addClass('hide');
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, I haven't been able to resolve it yet. I'm not familiar with the `currentTarget` call. Is there something similar for a class? And what if the button is a child. So like this: `.btn-a > .btn`? Is this applicable for jQuery?

Please note that answers are great, but they need explanation on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Could you please let me know how `#btn-b` can trigger `#btn-a` in order to show the `#form-popup`? This scenario is missing.

Comment: There is no need of invoking trigger method. In the above script, we are checking which button was clicked with the help of the property currentTarget.id of object e. According to the clicked button, we are performing the operation.